# Finding Probability of different Dice Rolls

Tags: probability

> A fair die is thrown three times:
>
> - What is the probability of getting: three sixes?
> - What is the probability of getting: six, one, six?

**My solution:**

Probability of getting three sixes:

$$\Pr(\text{1st dice six}) + \Pr(\text{2nd six}) + \Pr(\text{3rd six})$$
$$ = \frac{1}{6} \frac{5}{6} \frac{5}{6} + \frac{5}{6} \frac{1}{6} \frac{5}{6} + \frac{5}{6} \frac{5}{6} \frac{1}{6} = 3 \cdot \frac{25}{216} = \frac{75}{216} = \frac{25}{72}$$

Probability of getting six, one, six:

$$\Pr(\text{1st dice six}) + \Pr(\text{2nd one}) + \Pr(\text{3rd six})$$
$$ = \frac{1}{6} \frac{5}{6} \frac{5}{6} + \frac{5}{6} \frac{1}{6} \frac{5}{6} + \frac{5}{6} \frac{5}{6} \frac{1}{6} = 3 \cdot \frac{25}{216} = \frac{75}{216} = \frac{25}{72}$$

*Am I on the right track?*

---

### *Update:*

The problem am trying to solve does not specify order. Can we assume that order matters?

How about the following question, would the result be different from the initial question?

> A fair die is thrown three times:
>
> - What is the probability of getting: three sixes, where the first throw MUST be six?
> - What is the probability of getting: six, one, six, where the first throw MUST also be six?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the first probability would be $\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^3$, that is, Pr(1st dice six and 2nd six and 3rd six). The probability of getting six, one, six (the order matters) would be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Am I on the right track?*

No.

You've calculated: $$\mathsf P\left({\substack{(\text{first die is 6 and second and third are not 6})\text{ or }\\(\text{second die is 6 and first and third are not 6})\text{ or }\\(\text{third die is 6 and first and second are not 6})}}\right)$$

You should be looking for $$\mathsf P\Big(\text{first die is 6 and second die is 6 and third die is 6}\Big)$$

---

Likewise you've calculated: $$\mathsf P\left({\substack{(\text{first die is 6 and second and third are not 6})\text{ or }\\(\text{second die is 1 and first and third not are 1})\text{ or }\\(\text{third die is 6 and first and second are not 6})}}\right)$$

You should be looking for $$\mathsf P\Big(\text{first die is 6 and second die is 1 and third die is 6}\Big)$$

---

Hint:

- Use the Product Rule for the probability of the conjunction of *independent* events.  ("Conjunction" is "and", "intersection", et cetera.)
- Use the Additive Rule for the probability of the disjunction of exclusive events (also called "disjoint events"). ("Disjunction" is "or", "union", et cetera)

### ---

For your **Update**, consider this:, what is the probability that the *first die is a six* when it is given that the *first die is a six*?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you computing. But based on the statement of your problem. The total no. of outcomes are $6^3$.

## For first case:

The only favorable outcome is $(6,6,6)$ thus the probability is $\frac{1}{216}$.

## For second case:

The favorable outcomes are $(6,6,1), (6,1,6), (1,6,6)$ thus the probability is $\frac{3}{216}=\frac{1}{72}$.

Comment: The way the question is formulated is unclear. Why say "six, one, six" if the order is not to matter?